# Python list comprehension to return edge values of a list

Tags: python, data-structures, iteration, list-comprehension

If I have a list in python such as:

```
stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

with length n (in this case 9) and I am interested in creating lists of length n/2 (in this case 4). I want all possible sets of n/2 values in the original list, for example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], ..., [9, 1, 2, 3]
```

is there some list comprehension code I could use to iterate through the list and retrieve all of those sublists? I don't care about the order of the values within the lists, I am just trying to find a clever method of generating the lists.

Comment: I suppose I was not clear. I am only interested in sublists that are made up of contiguous values from the original list, including wrap-arounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
>>> n=len(stuff)
>>>
>>> [(stuff+stuff[:n/2-1])[i:i+n/2] for i in range(n)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 1], [8, 9, 1, 2], [9, 1, 2, 3]]
>>>
```

**Note**: above code is based on assumption from your example

```
[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], ..., [9, 1, 2, 3]
```

If you really need all possible values, you need to use itertools.permutations or combinations function as others suggested.

Answer (score 5):

What you need is [combinations function from itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)
(EDIT: use permutation if the order is important)

Note that this function is not available at Python 2.5. In that case you can copy the code from the above link:

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

and then

```
stuff = range(9)
what_i_want = [i for i in combinations(stuff, len(stuff)/2)]
```

Comment: The list of numbers was only an example. Would this code work for, say, a list of strings?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.permutations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) or [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) (depending on whether you want, for example, both `[1,2,3,4]` and `[4,3,2,1]` or not) with the optional second argument to specify length.

```
stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

itertools.permutations(stuff, 4) # will return all possible lists of length 4
itertools.combinations(stuff, 4) # will return all possible choices of 4 elements
```

This is assuming that you don't only want contiguous elements.

### Update

Since you specified that you don't care about order, what you're probably looking for is `itertools.combinations()`.